# Unpublish gerrit change

Tags: gerrit

I have accidentally pushed a change to gerrit that should have been pushed as a draft. Now I'd like to unpublish the change back to a draft.

Pushing it again to `refs/drafts/*` doesn't work as it isn't changed.

**Update:**

I followed the suggestions of [mvp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1734130/mvp) and [HiB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1342413/hib); I abandoned the change, amended the commit message (removing the change-id, letting the post-commit hook generate a new change-id) and pushed it again. This resulted in a 'new' draft change. At first it looks OK, but history etc. isn't preserved of course. Not a big issue, but not the clean solution I'm looking for.

Comment: you can always abandon it and push again

Comment: amend only the commit message, then push again

Comment: @mvp When I abandon the change I cannot push again without changing the change-ID.

Comment: @HiB When amending the commit message it it important to note that really only the change-ID matters.

Comment: what history issue do you have?

Comment: @HiB I like to keep a history of patches, even for drafts.

Comment: i think you dont miss any history - since you could push your change to draft..I dont get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a change is published you cannot set it back to draft, but you may create new draft patch sets for a published change.