# Undo publish of a draft in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a draft in gerrit and pressed the publish button by misstake. How can I move my commit back to a draft without abandoning it and commiting again?

Comment: This is not possible. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19153147

Comment: I actually just pushed it to refs/drafts/master again and it got the drafts status. However it is not listed in the drafts list in gerrit. I have reported this as a bug.